# webpack 4.1.1 -> The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli. -> No git binary found in $PATH

Tags: windows, git, npm, webpack

I just ran the command `npm-check-updates -a` and updated `webpack` to 4.1.1. I got the same error as everyone else at first:

> The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli. Please install
>   'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
>   -> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
>   -> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D

However when I try to run `npm install webpack-cli -D` I get the following error:

> npm ERR! code ENOGIT
>
> npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
>
> npm ERR! Failed using git.
>
> npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

Why does `webpack` require `git` to be installed?

If anyone else gets this error and just want to continue you can install the following program, make sure to enable windows command prompt during install.

https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: Surely npm requires git to be installed?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Nope, I have been able to run `npm install` and `webpack` before this without a problem.

Comment: Hmm. Neither does webpack-cli require git...